# Bind object of same type to `this` in class constructor

Tags: typescript, oop, generics

I have a simple abstract class which is supposed to construct a `T` object, and I need to assign it to `this` in the constructor.

```
abstract class Foo<T>{
    
    private getChildConstructor(): {new (): T} {
      return this.constructor as {new (): T};
    }


    private processObject(cls: ClassConstructor<T>): T{
      ..... // Returns a freshly constructed object of type T
    }

    constructor(){
      let obj = this.processObject(this.getChildConstructor())

      this = obj; // Bind newly created object of same type T to this
    }
}
```

I am getting:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property
```

I have also tried using `Object.bind(this, obj);` instead of left-hand assignment, but this returns an empty object `T{}`;

What is the correct way of binding an object of same type to `this` in the `constructor` itself?

Comment: I guess you mean `Object.assign` instead of `Object.bind`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The subclasses constructors are being called by design so why call them in `Foo`?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to achieve is a factory instead of a superclass